# SharePoint 2016 TaxonomyInternalService.json 404

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, 404, enterprise-keywords

I have enabled Enterprise Keywords on a document library in my site collection. When trying to apply keywords to the properties of an item, I get an alert stating "The server method 'GetMatches' failed".

Looking into it further I can see there is a 404 on 'https://sitecollection/_vti_bin/TaxonomyInternalService.json/GetMatches'.

I can get to other things located in '/_vti_bin' and I can also see the TaxonomyInternalService.json file on the web front end server. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

By default, when you enable **Enterprise Keywords** on SharePoint Document Library, you can apply keywords to the properties of an item.
[image]

But **404 error** occurred, **which means that there is no "GetMatches" method or cannot use "GetMatches" method in your SharePoint 2016 environment**.

I suggest you consider the following two suggestions：

1.Install the latest Security updates for SharePoint Enterprise Server 2016

[Description of the security update for SharePoint Enterprise Server 2016: August 11, 2020](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4484476/security-update-for-sharepoint-enterprise-server-2016-august-11-2020)

2.Fixing the missing Enterprise features references in the content database

---

"To fix the problem with references to Enterprise SharePoint features, I used the SharePoint Feature Administration and Clean Up Tool, which basically enables us to delete from the Farm, Web Application, Site Collection and sub sites any references to features that are not installed in the farm. The version I used was the version 2.4.8 that you can download here, that supports SharePoint 2016. The version 3.0, for some reason, didn’t detect the farm, which made it useless (maybe a beta version, not sure)."

---

More information, please refer to this article [SharePoint 2016 Upgrade: How to solve the “Feature is referenced in database but isn’t installed on the current farm” error](https://blogit.create.pt/miguelisidoro/2018/09/16/sharepoint-farm-update-how-to-solve-the-feature-is-referenced-in-database-but-isnt-installed-on-the-current-farm-error-in-a-sharepoint-2016-farm/).